# NgbModal in Angular HttpErrorInterceptor triggered from a Select throws ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

My very specific scenario is:

I have a select with two way NbModel binding and a (change) handler.

```html
<select
    id="dropdownDoesNotWork"
    [(ngModel)]="value1"
    (change)="onChange($event.target.value);"
  >
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="400">400: Bad Request</option>
  </select>
```

the `onChange` handler calls an API with `HttpClient` which results in an error

The Error is picked up in an `HttpInterceptor`, where an ng-bootstrap modal is opened.

At this point the following error results:

> Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ng-untouched: true'. Current value: 'ng-untouched: false'.

I can work around this issue by changing the template such that the select control is marked as touched in the `(change)` output.

```html
  <select
    id="dropdownWorks"
    [(ngModel)]="value2"
    #selectModel="ngModel"
    (change)="selectModel.control.markAsTouched(); onChange($event.target.value);"
  >
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="400">400: Bad Request</option>
  </select>
```

While I can work around it, it seems unreasonable to have to do this as a preventative measure on all controls.

Is there an alternate way to open this modal without triggering this issue?

Stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-expression-changed-issue

Repo
https://github.com/rcollette/angular-expression-changed-issue

Comment: The issue exists with latest versions of Angular and ng-bootstrap as well.  See NG8 branch here https://github.com/rcollette/angular-expression-changed-issue/tree/Ng8Update